# I want to plot a gaussian pulse in MATLAB in the frequency domain, with its centre at the highest value

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, gaussian

I have tried one way but i am getting 2 peaks at the edges as shown in the picture. I have used 1 part of my code for the signal generation where i used the gauspuls command (reference: www.simsonic.fr) and for plotting the frequency spectrum, i picked up the code from a previous post.

The screenshot contains the relevant signals.the top for the frequency domain signal, bottom one is of the source signal.

%for signal generation

```
f0=0.5; 
t0=1.5;
bndwdth=2; 
duration=2*t0; 

timebase=(0:round(duration/dt)-1)'*dt;
[signalI,signalQ]=gauspuls(timebase-t0,f0,bndwdth);
signal=signalQ;
%signal=signal/max(signal);
signal=20*signal;

figure(2)
plot(timebase,signal,'.-')
title('source signal')
xlabel('time (µs)')

%for fft:
midf=5e5;
figure(1)
L=1000;
fs=midf*10;
%NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
NFFT=2286;
Mb = fft(signal,NFFT)/L;
f = fs*linspace(0,1,NFFT); %Frequency Vector 
plot(f,abs(Mb))
title('Gaussian Pulse in Frequency Domain in bone')
xlabel('Frequency (f)')
ylabel('|Magnitude(f)|')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE, as the quality of your screenshots is very bad, and the main body of your question is your code, I am not sure what exactly your problem is. Please edit your question and add the information what your goal is (desired output) ...

Comment: Also, look up `fftshift` in Matlab's documentation, and their explanation on how to plot a spectrum in `doc fft`.

Comment: Yes, but @MBaz, i looked up the fftshift in MATLAB, it gives all the zero frequency content in the centre. @ irreducible i will take your feedback, correcting the same.

Comment: @KunalKhosla Edit your question to explain _what you expect_ to obtain, and how that is different from _what you're obtaining_.

Comment: I expected a peak at the maximum amplitude at the centre frequency ie. 500Khz but i am getting the peaks at 0 and 1Mhz.

Comment: You don't seem to have read the Matlab documents I pointed you to.

Comment: Please read the earlier comment, fft shift puts the dc frequency component in the center, my aim is to show the maximum frequency component in the centre. Any alternatives to fft?

Comment: Hi MBaz, it seems fftshift did work, thanks for the advise.:)